# installing a web api on a server from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, windows-2003-webserver

I am new to the web development world and I developed , finally, a web api using visual studio 2012 from my local PC and it works perfectly fine.

now I need to deploy it on a server and I have no clue from were to start. Can someone guide me (or at least give me a link on how to do that) . All the resources I found online are for people with some experience in the web development and /or with server knowlege.

from my understanding , I will do a remote desktop into the server and install it but I don t know what will be done....

also , I know that the server runs Windows 2003 , and I know for a fact that VS2012 runs on Windows 7 and 8 only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio's Publish wizard to publish your site.

This will create a deployment package of DDLs and whatever static files your site uses, and copy it over FTP or the file system.

Comment: not really true, the web api will only work if the windows 2003 server is running sp2 and framework 4.0.